# Can anyone recommend me a very good pre-trained model for face or head detection?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, convolution, object-detection

I really need to know the best pre-trained models to detect faces and/or peoples' head. Not a face recognition model, but only to classify whether an object is a person's head/face or not.

I'm implementing one on top of `Resnet50` from `tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50`, but I'm not sure if it's a good approach.

Other models like `centernet` and `efficientnet` in `tensorflow` are pre-trained to detect several objects, but I'm not sure  if I can also use it for this purpose.

I need something better than those provided by `OpenCV` (e.g. `cv2.HOGDescriptor`, `cv2.CascadeClassifier`, etc.).

Comment: Any update on this? does anyone know about any pretrained head detection model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using facenet pretrained model to detect faces in image, but i thing ti will not detect the head, so i suggest that you train object detection model to detect faces and heads.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me check this `facenet`. Is it for face detection or specially for face recognition?

Comment: it is face detection model also u can use it as feature extractor for faces, then you can apply ML algorithim like knn or svm to make the face recognition.

Comment: Sounds great! I'll be right back after my tests...

Comment: Nice explanation here:

[link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. Now I can continue my investigation. Your help was very important. Now I'm implementing and comparing Google's Facenet,  Facebook's DeepFace, Oxford's VGG Face and  OpenFace from Universidade Carnegie Mellon. I'm going to use their Face detection feature without the recognition part as you suggested. FaceNet will probably be the chosen one as I'm checking it's highlighted as the most accuracy one in the state of art.